# d3js - Creating Asterplot-like Charts (example included)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, diagram

I'm new to d3js, but am familiar with javascript and the principles of data-visualisation.

I've tried to achieve an effects to visualize 2 dimensions of data using the aster plot diagram, but can't really get this thing to work like expected.

Attached you'll find the diagram I'm trying to recreate and my example code.
It would be huge if you could tell me how to get it working - or how to optimize it! :)

[D3JS - Aster Plot Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYOTr.png)

This is how I think the data and the code should look like.. kinda.. (Pseudo-Code incoming..)

Data Example:

```
    var testData = {
      maxPoints: 10,
      color: '#bababa',
      border: {
        width: 1,
        color: '#ffffff'
      },
      items: [
        {
          name: 'Looks',
          color: '#2976dd',
          weight: 0.37,
          points: 8
        },{
          name: 'Charm',
          color: '#87bd24',
          weight: 0.03,
          points: 5
        },{
          name: 'Honesty',
          color: '#406900',
          weight: 0.16,
          points: 7
        },{
          name: 'Humour',
          color: '#ffb200',
          weight: 0.31,
          points: 9
        },{
          name: 'Intelligence',
          color: '#f78200',
          weight: 0.12,
          points: 0
        }
      ]
    };
```

Code Example:

```
  var archs = [];
  // Loop through each item
  var circleRadius = 400;
  var innerRadius = 100;

  var startAngle = 0;
  var endAngle = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < testData.items.length; i++) {
    // Draw each arch
    var maxPoints = testData.maxPoints;
    var archHeight = (circleRadius - innerRadius) / maxPoints;
    var startRadius = innerRadius;

    endAngle += testData.items[i].weight;

    for (var j = 0; j < maxPoints; j++) {
      var color = testData.color;
      // draw arch - don't know how to colorize accordingly..
      if (testData.items[i].points < j) {
        // color this arc somehow..
        color = testData.items[i].color;
      }

        d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(startAngle)
        .endAngle(endAngle)
        .innerRadius(startRadius)
        .outerRadius(startRadius+archHeight);

      // Increase startRadius
      startRadius += archHeight;
    }

    // Increase startAngle
    startAngle = endAngle;
  }
```

Somehow my code looks way more complicated.. Though it's still pseudo-code..
I'm still struggling.. If someone could give me a hint or some working code to start from I would be very thankful!

Thanks in advance
- Chris

Comment: Have you seen this one: http://bl.ocks.org/bbest/2de0e25d4840c68f2db1 ? If yes, what would prevent you from using it as a base?

Comment: Hey - I've seen this code!
I'm still missing some pricinples of D3JS logic.. Another way would be to create concentrical Pie/Donu-Charts and to shrinken the outerRadius..
But I thought my way would be legit aswell.

The Problem with the AsterPlot: I need to draw a grid view like in the image example - that's why I'll have to make some looping-magic :/

Comment: OK, I'll try an answer when I find some time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation which replicates your diagram.  It essentially builds concentric donut charts based on weight and then colors the slices based on points:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> 
  .arc path {
    stroke: #fff;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var testData = {
      maxPoints: 10,
      color: '#bababa',
      border: {
        width: 1,
        color: '#ffffff'
      },
      items: [{
        name: 'Looks',
        color: '#2976dd',
        weight: 0.37,
        points: 8
      }, {
        name: 'Charm',
        color: '#87bd24',
        weight: 0.03,
        points: 5
      }, {
        name: 'Honesty',
        color: '#406900',
        weight: 0.16,
        points: 7
      }, {
        name: 'Humour',
        color: '#ffb200',
        weight: 0.31,
        points: 9
      }, {
        name: 'Intelligence',
        color: '#f78200',
        weight: 0.12,
        points: 0
      }]
    };

    var width = 500,
      height = 500;
      color = d3.scale.category20();
    
    // inner radius
    var iR = 75,
    // radius of each concentric arc
        r = ((Math.min(width, height) / 2) - iR)  / testData.maxPoints;
        
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.weight;
      })
      .padAngle(.01);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(testData.items))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    // iterate our number of rings
    d3.range(testData.maxPoints)
      .forEach(function(i){
        
        // generate an arc
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(r * (i + 1) + iR)
            .innerRadius(r * i + iR);
        
        // fill it, if appropriate
        g.append("path")
          .attr("d", arc)
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (i < d.data.points)
              return color(d.data.name);
            else
              return "#eee"
          });
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: Wow!! Big thanks!
I'm gonna check out your code..
I've tried to do it this way aswell.